# Map function in Keras

Tags: keras

In tutorial 'Text classification from scratch',

```
# Let's make a text-only dataset (no labels):
text_ds = raw_train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)
```

How to understand this `map` function here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the `map` function is helping in doing asynchronous processing. The example in the tutorial mentioned is using text-only data. It is discarding the labels. This is done using `lambda` function `x, y --> x`. This transformation is applied to each sample of data on the CPU of host machine while your GPU is processing the previous sample of data. This asynchronous processing is being done by `map` function. Since the GPU doesn't have to wait for next batch of data, you get full utilization.